# How to know the hard disk capacity for sure and how to recover lost partitions?

Tags: hard-drive, bootcamp, disk-utility, partition

After I have played with boot camp, the disk became only 250 GB out of 500 GB.
disk utility, terminal, and system information are showing that disk capacity is 250 GB.
Although I am sure that the disk is originally 500 or to be precise I am sure that those same programs displayed 500 before, I'd like to know how can I know the real capacity for sure and of course is there any solutions to undo whatever I did that corrupted the disk.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Apple exposes the hardware size of the drive in several places.

- About this Mac in the Apple Menu - click storage tab
- System Information app (click System Report... in About this Mac - overview section)

  - there's a storage general category
  - there's specific storage details (firmware / bus position / bus speed) for the SATA / AHCI / NVMe section based on how your storage is physically connected to the hardware
- Disk Utility (in /Applications/Utilities)

The undo is either finesse the partition table (there are hundreds of questions here on how to change `gpt` and `diskutil` or to backup your files, and erase install a new OS which basically boots to another recovery OS and runs Disk Utility to repartition / erase the drive.

Good luck with your choice of path to get the storage back and set.

Answer (score 1):

The Terminal application command shown below outputs the size of each drive that has not been ejected from the Mac.

```
diskutil list
```

There are three types of partitioning used to store a Mac files. The command `diskutil list` presents the partition types as either `Apple_HFS`, `Apple_CoreStorage` or `Apple_APFS`. Each of these types of partitioning has a generic command to reclaim lost space. If it appears none of the generic commands fit your particular problem, you could try posting a new question. Your question should also include the output from the `diskutil list` command and the model/year of your Mac.

### Apple_HFS

For this type of partitioning, the output from the `diskutil list` command should appears similar to what is shown below.

```
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        +1.0 TB     disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS Macintosh HD            499.2 GB   disk0s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Recovery HD             650.0 MB   disk0s3
```

Here there is approximately 500 GB to restore to `disk0s2`. The generic command is given below.

```
diskutil  resizeVolume  disk0s2  R
```

The results are shown below.

```
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        +1.0 TB     disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                  Apple_HFS Macintosh HD            999.0 GB   disk0s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot                         650.0 MB   disk0s3
```

### Apple_CoreStorage

For this type of partitioning, the output from the `diskutil list` command should appears similar to what is shown below.

> Note: This type of partitioning often involves more than one physical drive.

```
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        +1.0 TB     disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:          Apple_CoreStorage Macintosh HD            500.1 GB   disk0s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Boot OS X               134.2 MB   disk0s3

/dev/disk1 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                  Apple_HFS Macintosh HD           +499.7 GB   disk1
                                 Logical Volume on disk0s2
                                 73BC8A1D-61C6-45D7-8509-042F21133C4D
                                 Unencrypted
```

Here there is approximately 500 GB to restore to `disk0s2`. The generic command is given below. Instead of using the identifier `disk0s2`, you need to substitute the UUID (`73BC8A1D-61C6-45D7-8509-042F21133C4D`) of the logical volume on `disk0s2`.

```
diskutil  cs  resizeStack  73BC8A1D-61C6-45D7-8509-042F21133C4D  0
```

The results are shown below.

```
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        +1.0 TB     disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:          Apple_CoreStorage Macintosh HD            999.7 GB   disk0s2
   3:                 Apple_Boot Boot OS X               134.2 MB   disk0s4

/dev/disk1 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:                  Apple_HFS Macintosh HD           +999.3 GB   disk1
                                 Logical Volume on disk0s2
                                 73BC8A1D-61C6-45D7-8509-042F21133C4D
                                 Unencrypted
```

> Note: The identifier `disk0s4` should be `disk0s3`. This can be corrected by restarting the computer.

### Apple_APFS

For this type of partitioning, the output from the `diskutil list` command should appears similar to what is shown below.

> Note: This type of partitioning often involves more than one physical drive.

```
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        +1.0 TB     disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk1         500.0 GB   disk0s2
```

Here there is approximately 500 GB to restore to `disk0s2`. The generic command is given below. Instead of using the identifier `disk0s2`, you need to substitute the container (`disk1`) for for `disk0s2`.

```
diskutil  apfs  resizeContainer  disk1  0
```

The results are shown below.

```
/dev/disk0 (internal, physical):
   #:                       TYPE NAME                    SIZE       IDENTIFIER
   0:      GUID_partition_scheme                        +1.0 TB     disk0
   1:                        EFI EFI                     209.7 MB   disk0s1
   2:                 Apple_APFS Container disk1         999.8 GB   disk0s2
```