# mac wont boot anymore after running bootcamp

Tags: macos, bootcamp, usb, startup, keybindings

It went fine until it restarted and showed a black screen with"insert bootable device" which was right there.
It wont do anything else until I hold the power button to turn it off. rebooting shows the same screen. none ofthe start up key combinations like alt, cmd+r, etc work or seem todo anything.

any suggestions? 0_o i did bootcamp by the book, followed apple's instructions, but it seems almost as if it bricked my whole mac...

Answer (score 1):

I wouldn’t panic, but I would think how recent your backups are.

1. The NVRAM stores where to boot so to bypass that, power off and hold the option key when you boot. If your Mac OS drive shows, select that and see how it boots.
2. Once you’re back in macOS - use system preferences to change the startup disk or consider resetting NVRAM with the Command - Option - P - R key commands.

If that doesn’t work, I would boot to recovery and see if you can get into Disk Utility and take a picture of how the drive is partitioned or better get some details from the Utilities / Terminal app.

- [How to know the hard disk capacity for sure and how to recover lost partitions?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/316634/how-to-know-the-hard-disk-capacity-for-sure-and-how-to-recover-lost-partitions)

The above question lines up the various Core Storage / APFS / plain disk formats for all MacOS versions since OS X.